# Asynchronous object destruction service

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

Inspired by the recent Stack Overflow question [“Safely release a resource on a different thread”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854451/safely-release-a-resource-on-a-different-thread), I wrote the following `destruction_service<T>`.  Please refer to the `class` `template`'s DocString for more information (and let me know in your review if it is insufficient).

**destruction_service.hxx**

```
/**
 * @file destruction_service.hxx
 *
 * @brief
 *         Provides the `my::destruction_service` class template for
 *         asynchronous object destruction.
 *
 */

#ifndef DESTRUCTION_SERVICE_HXX
#define DESTRUCTION_SERVICE_HXX

#include <cassert>             // assert
#include <condition_variable>  // std::condition_variable
#include <mutex>               // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <thread>              // std::thread
#include <type_traits>         // std::enable_if_t, std::is_nothrow_{move_constructible,destructible}
#include <utility>             // std::move
#include <vector>              // std::vector

#include "syncio.hxx"          // syncio::print_log


namespace my
{

  /**
   * @brief
   *         An asynchronous object destruction service.
   *
   * An instance of this class owns a worker thread that asynchronously
   * destroys objects.  This might be useful for threads that have high
   * responsiveness requirements and objects with (potentially) long-running
   * destructors.
   *
   * To-be-destroyed objects can be scheduled for destruction by means of the
   * `schedule_destruction` member function.  It takes its argument by rvalue
   * reference assuming that destructing a moved-away-from object is
   * considerably cheaper.  If you are using this service to destroy smart
   * pointers, be aware that only scheduling the *last* instance of a shared
   * pointer will cause the managed object to be destroyed asynchronously.  `T`
   * is required to have a non-throwing move constructor and its destructor
   * must not throw either.
   *
   * If you have to destruct objects of different types, consider using a
   * polymorphic wrapper to perform type erasure.  The default is
   * non-polymorphic, however, because type erasure requires additional dynamic
   * memory allocation which is obnoxious for destruction.  Also, smart
   * pointers already provide some degree of polymorphism, provided that all
   * types you need to destruct derive from a common base class that has a
   * `virtual` destructor.
   *
   * @tparam T
   *         type of object to be destroyed
   *
   */
  template
  <
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value>,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value>
  >
  class destruction_service final
  {

  public:

    /** @brief Type that is destructed by this service. */
    using object_type = T;

  private:

    /** @brief Worker thread destroying objects. */
    std::thread worker_ {};

    /** @brief Mutex to protect the object queue. */
    mutable std::mutex mutex_ {};

    /** @brief Condition variable to signal changes to the object queue. */
    mutable std::condition_variable condvar_ {};

    /** @brief Object queue of to-be-destructed items. */
    std::vector<object_type> queue_ {};

    /** @brief Signal that no more objects will be scheduled for destruction. */
    bool done_ {};

  public:

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Creates a new destruction service with its own worker thread.
     *
     */
    destruction_service()
    {
      this->worker_ = std::thread {&destruction_service::do_work_, this};
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Destroys all remaining objects and then shuts down the service.
     *
     */
    ~destruction_service() noexcept
    {
      syncio::print_log(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
      auto lck = this->lock_queue_();
      this->done_ = true;
      lck.unlock();
      this->condvar_.notify_all();
      if (this->worker_.joinable())
        this->worker_.join();
      assert(this->queue_.empty());
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Schedules an object for asynchronous destruction.
     *
     * This function may safely be called concurrently.
     *
     * @param object
     *         object to be destructed
     *
     */
    void
    schedule_destruction(object_type&& object)
    {
      auto lck = this->lock_queue_();
      this->queue_.push_back(std::move(object));
      lck.unlock();
      this->condvar_.notify_all();
    }

  private:

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Worker thread main loop.
     *
     * Until the `done_` flag is not set, this function waits on the object
     * queue and removes and destructs any items in it.  It is guaranteeds that
     * the queue be empty after this function returns unless items were added
     * after the `done_` flag has been set.
     *
     */
    void
    do_work_()
    {
      syncio::print_log("destruction thread");
      auto things = std::vector<object_type> {};
      for (auto stop = false; true; stop = this->is_done_())
        {
          auto lck = this->lock_queue_();
          while (this->queue_.empty() && !this->done_)
            this->condvar_.wait(lck);
          this->queue_.swap(things);
          lck.unlock();
          syncio::print_log("about to destroy ", things.size(), " objects...");
          things.clear();
          if (stop)
            break;
        }
      assert(this->queue_.empty());
      assert(things.empty());
      syncio::print_log("good bye");
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Fetches the value of the `done_` member in a synchronized
     *         manner.
     *
     * @returns
     *         value of the `done_` member variable
     *
     */
    bool
    is_done_() const noexcept
    {
      auto lck = this->lock_queue_();
      return this->done_;
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Returns a lock for the object queue.
     *
     * @returns
     *         lock for the object queue
     *
     */
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>
    lock_queue_() const noexcept
    {
      return std::unique_lock<std::mutex> {this->mutex_};
    }

  };  // struct destruction_service

}  // namespace my


#endif  // #ifndef DESTRUCTION_SERVICE_HXX
```

A few design decisions (please critique if you disagree):

- The type of objects that can be destructed is not erased for the reasons mentioned in the DocString.  This also means that I cannot use queue poisoning in the destructor but instead have to use the `done_` flag.  I'm somewhat uncomfortable with the resulting control logic of the main loop in the `do_work_` function.
- The `schedule_destruction` function might have to resize a `std::vector` while holding to a lock.  I normally wouldn't do this but in this case, it seemed preferable to have the main thread execute as fast as possible.  I don't care if the destruction (worker) thread is blocked for a short while.  Its work isn't very urgent anyway.  It is also assumed that reallocations will be infrequent (see next item).
- The object queue is implemented by a pair of `std::vector`s that grow dynamically as needed but never shrink.  I thought about using a `std::deque` instead to avoid potentially keeping large amounts of memory that are no longer needed after a burst of submissions but the extra capacity of the `std::vector`s reducing the number of memory allocations in the critical section convinced me that this is the lesser evil.  On the other hand, resizing a `std::deque` is a constant-time operation, while resizing a `std::vector` is linear.

For completeness, I'll also show the `syncio.hxx` header that provides the thread-safe `syncio::print_log` function and a small example usage in `main.cxx`.  Feel free to comment about these files as well if you want to but please focus on the `destruction_service.hxx` file.

**syncio.hxx**

```
/**
 * @file syncio.hxx
 *
 * @brief
 *         Simple synchronized (thread-safe) I/O functions.
 *
 * The functions provided by this header are only thread-safe if they are not
 * mixed with other I/O functions.  Synchronization happens via an internal
 * mutex.  Locking is pessimistic, using the same mutex for all streams,
 * assuming that all streams might interleave.
 *
 */

#ifndef SYNCIO_HXX
#define SYNCIO_HXX

#include <iostream>  // std::ostream, std::clog, std::endl
#include <mutex>     // std::mutex, std::lock_guard
#include <thread>    // std::this_thread::get_id


namespace syncio
{

  /** @brief Internal private `namespace`. */
  namespace syncio_hxx
  {

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Returns a reference to the singleton instance of the I/O mutex.
     *
     * @returns
     *         reference to the mutex protecting I/O operations
     *
     */
    std::mutex&
    get_iomutex() noexcept
    {
      static std::mutex iomutex {};
      return iomutex;
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Helper struct to print a variadic number of arguments.
     *
     * @tparam ...
     *         ignored
     *
     */
    template <typename...>
    struct printer_helper;

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Specialization for one or more arguments.
     *
     * @tparam HeadT
     *         type of the first argument
     *
     * @tparam TailTs...
     *         types of the remaining arguments (if any)
     *
     */
    template <typename HeadT, typename... TailTs>
    struct printer_helper<HeadT, TailTs...>
    {

      /**
       * @brief
       *         Inserts all arguments followed by a newline into the given
       *         stream and flushes it.
       *
       * @param os
       *         stream to print to
       *
       * @param head
       *         first argument to print
       *
       * @param tail...
       *         remaining arguments to print
       *
       */
      static void
      print(std::ostream& os, const HeadT& head, const TailTs&... tail)
      {
        os << head;
        printer_helper<TailTs...>::print(os, tail...);
      }

    };

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Specialization for zero arguments.
     *
     */
    template <>
    struct printer_helper<>
    {

      /**
       * @brief
       *         Inserts a newline into the given stream and flushes it.
       *
       * @param os
       *         stream to print to
       *
       */
      static void
      print(std::ostream& os)
      {
        os << std::endl;
      }

    };

  }  // namespace syncio_hxx

  /**
   * @brief
   *         Prints a message to the given stream in a synchronized
   *         (thread-safe) manner.
   *
   * The arguments are inserted as if by successively streaming them with
   * `operator<<`.  After the last item, a newline is inserted and the stream
   * flushed.
   *
   * @param os
   *         stream to print to
   *
   * @param items...
   *         items to make up the message
   *
   */
  template <typename... Ts>
  void
  print(std::ostream& os, const Ts&... items)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard {syncio_hxx::get_iomutex()};
    syncio_hxx::printer_helper<Ts...>::print(os, items...);
  }

  /**
   * @brief
   *         Prints a log message to `std::log` in a synchronized (thread-safe)
   *         manner.
   *
   * The arguments are prefixed with the ID of the current thread and
   * terminated by a newline.  The stream is flushed after printing the
   * message.
   *
   * @param items...
   *         items to make up the log message
   *
   */
  template <typename... Ts>
  void
  print_log(const Ts&... items)
  {
    print(std::clog, "[", std::this_thread::get_id(), "] ", items...);
  }

}  // namespace syncio


#endif  // #ifndef SYNCIO_HXX
```

**main.cxx**

```
/**
 * @file main.cxx
 *
 * @brief
 *         Example usage of the `my::destruction_service`.
 *
 */


#include <atomic>                   // std::atomic_int
#include <thread>                   // std::this_thread::{get_id,yield}
#include <utility>                  // std::exchange

#include "destruction_service.hxx"  // my::destruction_service
#include "syncio.hxx"               // syncio::print_log


namespace /* anonymous */
{

  /** @brief Number of `example` objects created thus far. */
  std::atomic_int example_count {};

  /** @brief ID of the main thread. */
  std::thread::id main_thread_id {};

  /**
   * @brief
   *         A dummy class.
   *
   * The destructor if this class `assert()`s that it is invoked on a thread
   * different from the main thread.  This is not the case for destructing
   * moved-away-from objects.
   *
   */
  class example
  {

  private:

    /** @brief ID of this object. */
    int id_ {-1};

  public:

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Creates a new object with a new ID.
     *
     */
    example() : id_ {example_count.fetch_add(1)}
    {
      syncio::print_log("creating object ", this->id_);
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Creates a copy of another object with the same ID.
     *
     * @param other
     *         object to copy
     *
     */
    example(const example& other) : id_ {other.id_}
    {
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Creates a copy of another object, stealing its ID.
     *
     * The moved-away-from object will get a negative ID.
     *
     * @param other
     *         object to move away from
     *
     */
    example(example&& other) noexcept : id_ {std::exchange(other.id_, -1)}
    {
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     *         Asserts that the object is either in a moved-away-from state or
     *         the current thread is different from the main thread.
     *
     */
    ~example() noexcept
    {
      syncio::print_log("destroying object ", this->id_);
      assert(this->id_ < 0 || std::this_thread::get_id() != main_thread_id);
      std::this_thread::yield();
    }

  };  // struct example

}  // namespace /* anonymous */


/**
 * @brief
 *         Launches a `my::destruction_service` and submits a dozen `example`
 *         objects to it.
 *
 */
int
main()
{
  main_thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
  syncio::print_log("main thread");
  my::destruction_service<example> destructor {};
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
      auto thing = example {};
      destructor.schedule_destruction(std::move(thing));
    }
}
```

I'm interested in feedback of any kind but in particular:

- Correctness, especially concurrency bugs.  It took me a while to get this into what I believe is now race and dead-lock free.
- Compliance with the C++14 standard and making good use of its features.
- Design of the interface.
- Performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To SFINAE or not to SFINAE**

Your class template definition starts with:

```
template
  <
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value>,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value>
  >
  class destruction_service final
```

but SFINAE is basically intended to remove candidates from an overload set. That's not really an issue here, so this seems unnecessarily verbose. What you want in this case is just the simple static asserts:

```
template <typename T>
class destruction_service final {
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value, "!");
    ...
```

**Locking**

Your `lock_queue_` is weird and unnecessary. Just construct a lock object, it'll be cleaner. Also if you find yourself writing `unlock()`, you're probably doing something wrong. In the case of your destructor, I would rewrite it as:

```
~destruction_service() noexcept
{
    syncio::print_log(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(this->mutex_);
        this->done_ = true;
    }
    this->condvar_.notify_all();
    if (this->worker_.joinable())
        this->worker_.join();
    assert(this->queue_.empty());
}
```

The bracing makes the locking intent clear and takes advantage of RAII. A similar construction can be used for `schedule_destruction`:

```
void schedule_destruction(object_type&& object)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(this->mutex_);
        this->queue_.push_back(std::move(object));
    }
    this->condvar_.notify_all();
}
```

Prefer `lock_guard` to `unique_lock` unless you really need a `unique_lock`.

**Lock-Free Queue**

If this is an optimization, I'd consider using a lock-free queue. You may find that most of your time comes from lock acquisition/release.

**`do_work_`()**

Your loop is:

```
for (auto stop = false; true; stop = this->is_done_()) { ... }
```

That's... weird construction. Why not just:

```
while (!this->is_done_()) { ... }
```

Next, [`std::condition_variable::wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) has an overload that takes a predicate. This clears intent a bit:

```
while (!this->is_done())
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(this->mutex_); // now we need unique
        this->condvar_.wait(lk, [this]{
            // waiting for one of these things to be true
            return !this->queue_.empty() || this->done_; 
        });
        this->queue_.swap(things);
    }
    // and now we're unlocked
    things.clear();
}

// we're done, so let's clean up. no lock necessary
this->queue_.clear();
```

**printer helper**

Behold, the wonder of pack expansion. No template specialization with `printer_helper_` necessary:

```
template <typename... Items>
void print(std::ostream& os, Items const&... items)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{...};

    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander{0,
        (void(os << items)
        , 0)...
    };
    os << std::endl;
}
```

**Usage of `this`**

You don't really need `this` in just about all of the places you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the review.; that are some good points.  Unfortunately, the proposed `while` loop is not equivalent to my weired `for` loop.  It does not guarantee that the two `assert`ions at the end of `do_work_` will hold.  It took me some debugging until I realized that and finally came up with my strange construct.  Your `print` template is truly amazing.  I wouldn't believe it could work until I've seen it.

Comment: @5gon12eder Then you probably want `for(;;) { ...; if (is_done_()) break; }`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either, because it has a race condition: by the time I check `is_done_()`, the queue is not guaranteed to be empty.  I may only exit the loop if I have seen the `done_` flag set and *after that* (or while still holding the lock) confirmed that `queue_.empty()`.

Comment: @5gon12eder I guess I don't understand the need for your asserts at all. Just do `queue_.clear();` at the end of the loop and use the form I suggest in the answer.

Comment: That, indeed, will do the trick!  After the `done_` flag is set, I can access the `queue_` without the need for locking.  Very nice.

Comment: @5gon12eder Added that note to my answer.

Comment: I finally went with `while (true) { auto lck = std::unique_lock<std::mutex> {this->mutex_}; if (this->done_) break; this->condvar_.wait(…); … }`.  It avoids taking the lock twice per iteration and I don't need the `is_done_` helper function any more.